# Why don't my SharedPreferences save on button click?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

So I am trying to add some values to my `SharedPreferences` but everytime I click the button it just goes with the default value of `00` so my if statement is always returning true even though it shouldn't.

```
private static final String SHARED_FREFS = "sharedPrefs";
private static final String STATE = "state";
```

And this is the button click event

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_FREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor =  sharedPreferences.edit();

                int currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getMinutes();
                String eh = sharedPreferences.getString(STATE,  "00");

                if(!Integer.toString(currentTime).equalsIgnoreCase(sharedPreferences.getString(STATE,  "00"))){
                    GetData();
                    editor.putString(STATE, Integer.toString(currentTime));
                    Log.e("ATTENTION!:", "METHOD HAS BEEN FIRED!");
                }
            }
        });
```

I am trying to store the current minute in there but it's not doing it.
Do I need a folder called data with a xml file in it named `sharedPrefs` ?

Comment: It should be `editor.putString(STATE, Integer.toString(currentTime)).commit()` . Or `apply()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why don't my SharedPreferences save on button click?

Because you forgot to save updates in your `SharedPreferences`

You need to use **`editor.apply();`** or **`editor.commit();`** after adding data in your `SharedPreferences`

SAMPLE

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_FREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor =  sharedPreferences.edit();

                int currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getMinutes();
                String eh = sharedPreferences.getString(STATE,  "00");

                if(!Integer.toString(currentTime).equalsIgnoreCase(sharedPreferences.getString(STATE,  "00"))){
                    GetData();
                    editor.putString(STATE, Integer.toString(currentTime));
                    editor.apply();
                    Log.e("ATTENTION!:", "METHOD HAS BEEN FIRED!");
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 4):

As I am seeing your code, always you need to use `editor.commit()` or `editor.apply()` after adding the data in shared-preference Editor. Which one should use, please see below:

`commit()` - this method runs synchronously, which means:

1. thread safe.
2. slow.
3. and always gives feedback.

`apply()` - this method runs asynchronously, which means:

1. not thread safe.
2. runs fast.
3. and does not give feedback.

Finally sharedPreferences instances are singleton with in a process it's safe to replace any instance of commit() with apply(), if you were already ignoring the return value.

Answer (score 3):

Always [commit](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor#commit()) or [apply](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor#apply()) on Editor after update anything on sharePrefs

```
mEditor.commit();
```